# Are quotes enabled by default in all organizations?

Tags: quote

Quotes were a feature that an organization had to opt-into by enabling them under Quote Settings. However, I see that in a number of our orgs, the setting is now "disable quotes" and the object is available. Did Salesforce automatically enable this feature for all existing orgs and now orgs must opt-out? Was this included in release notes anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Quotes have not been force-enabled for all orgs, nor do orgs need to opt-out of Quotes. I have numerous Developer Orgs without Quotes enabled, and I just now created a new Developer Org, and it did not have Quotes enabled. Someone must have turned it on in your orgs. You can check the Setup Audit Trail for the following message:

> Organization setup action: quotesEnabledOffOn has changed.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. I have an org where all admins claim they never enabled the feature so I will need to peruse the audit trail.